# decorating basic data types in go

Tags: go

I am starting new application in go.

I know that we can't monkey patch go code. So if we want to do some hacks with basic data types like int, float, string, etc.. its not possible.

So, i am thinking to create new type for these basic things and use them througout the application instead of the basic ones. Later if we want to overwrite some of these methods or we want to add some new methods, we can overwrite these new types.

Is this good way of doing??

Following is the sample code:

```
type NewInt Int
```

or

```
type NewInt struct{
    Int
}
```

Here if i am creating a variable like `var test NewInt = 16`, will it create 2 objects internally(one for basic int and other for newint) by creating memory issue?? or will it use same object for both??

How can i debug this scenario?? How can i collect all the existing objects in heap after creating a variable??

Comment: maybe the empty interface could help you https://tour.golang.org/methods/14

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Your code will be cluttered with type conversions, because every package except your own accepts and returns standard types. This will be especially painful with slices. Why do you want methods on standard types anyway? You can just as easily define functions instead. [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), and if you do: refactoring is easy in Go.

Comment: it wont internally create 2 objects, but like Peter said,Why do you want methods on standard types anyway?

Comment: Creating a struct with an Int in it is not the same as creating an extension of the Int type. Using type NewInt Int means that Int ==== NewInt. The other one is not the same, but rather a "class" with a field in it of type int

Comment: @nicksheen Sorry if this comment is OT, as I am using the questions here on SO to help learn go. Am I correct in saying that the empty interface sort of does the job of generics in c# (and perhaps java, but I know it way less than c#)?

Comment: @Bovaz https://golang.org/doc/faq#generics according to this I would say that you can use them for that yes

Comment: The basic types have no methods. Go is not Ruby. There are certainly cases where it can be very useful to create types based on primitive types, but I can't think of any case whatsoever where you'd want to use the same primitive-based type everywhere in your application. It sounds like you're trying to solve problems you haven't encountered yet - before you try to make Go do things it's not supposed to, just work with the language and standard library until you *actually encounter a problem*, rather than creating problems for yourself preemptively.

Comment: @nicksheen thank you

Answer (score 6):

I think the fundamental route that you are going down will cause you problems.

You shouldn't really be wrapping / mocking the primitive data types, such as `int`, `string` etc. But instead creating higher level abstractions; in the form of interfaces.

You mention needing to "overwite some methods" on your new types; but this should be done at the interface level and not the data type level.

You will also find it **much** harder to consume any other go packages, as you will constantly be converting from `NewInt` to `int` to pass into other packages.

If you provide an example of *when* you plan on using the `NewInt` type datatypes, then I can provide an example of how to do it with interfaces instead.

Comment: Besides the use of interfaces, *there are no methods to override on the Go primitives*. The question is based on a faulty premise.

Comment: I agree, I think the question is based on the assumption that there would be methods defined on new types, and then those methods could some how be mocked etc.